# ZF2 project does not updating via composer

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been given a zend project to work on, when i do the usual **composer.phar** install/update the existing ZF2 folder is unchanged, a new zend framework folder is created instead.

I ask this question because I updated once after deleting libraries in ZF2 folder and they were reinstalled (in the ZF2 folder).

If this is the current default behavior then all good, but I have a nagging feeling that i might not be updating correctly, and therefore not confident of the project behavior.

Is installing directly into existing ZF2 folder now defunct?

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 version < ~2.5 will download a folder `vendor` in which will put a new folder called `zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/all zend modules`.

In version 2.5+ ZF2 is using a new way of distributing its modules via separated meta packages, which makes it even easier to maintain. Of course the structure is different `/vendor/zendframework/all zend modules`

If you have any 3rd parties packages for example: `phpunit, fabpot, symfony, bjyoungblood` etc, they will be stored in your `vendor/packagename` folder, regardless of your ZF2 version.

However, there are few exceptions for modules like `zend developer tools and zendxml`, which will be installed in your `vendor/zendframework` folder.